Justification of wedge-determinant equality
In Do Carmo's Curves and Surfaces, he states the following:

Can someone explain the reasoning here?
And what is meant by for all $i,j,k,l = 1,2,3$? Aren't the $e$'s meant to be the three different components of the vectors $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v},\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}$?
**where the wedge product $\mathbf{u} \land \mathbf{v}$ is defined as:  unique vector in $\mathbb{R}^3$ characterized by
$$(\mathbf{u} \land \mathbf{v}) \cdot \mathbf{w} = \det{(u,v,w)} \quad \quad \textrm{for all } \mathbf{w} \in \mathbb{R}^3$$

I have seen this used as the definition of the inner product of bivectors, so if do Carmo is starting from a different definition you'll have to give it. As for your question, are you familiar with the fact that to prove that two bilinear maps are equal (say two inner products) it suffices to show that they are equal on a basis? This is the same thing but with multilinear maps.

@QiaochuYuan I have added in the definition of the wedge product. See above. I do understand the principle that you are referring to, but I'm not sure how the indexing  works in this case?

What do you mean by "how the indexing works in this case"? The $e_i$ are the standard basis vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so $e_1 = (1, 0, 0)$ and so forth. Is that your question?

@QiaochuYuan So technically speaking, is it saying that "it suffices to check that" the $e$ equality holds for all 81 ($3^4$) combinations of $i,j,k,l$?

Yes. This may seem like a lot of work but by antisymmetry a lot of the results are equal to zero on both sides, so the number of cases where both sides are nonzero isn't so bad. And you can also take advantage of the symmetry of the dot product.

You first verify that, using the definition of the wedge product (which is also known as the cross product), if $(i,j,k)$ is s cyclic permutation of $(1,2,3)$, then $$ e_i\wedge e_j = e_k. $$ From this, it is straightforward to verify that $$ (e_i\wedge e_j)\cdot(e_k\wedge e_l) = \delta_{ik}\delta_{jl} - \delta_{il}\delta_{jk} = (e_i\cdot e_k)(e_j\cdot e_l)-(e_i\cdot e_l)(e_j\cdot e_k).$$
